# WPF Change method assigned to button click temporarily

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I'm trying to change the button onclick handler / method assigned to button for a short time period.

In other words... user clicks button -> primary task of button executes -> if user clicks button again within... say 3 seconds -> secondary task of button executes.

If user does not click the button in 3 seconds, the primary task is restored to the button.

I've succeeded in changing and restoring the button functionality... but the secondary method is not being executed completely.

Here's the xaml and cs code... I've added comments in the cs code so it'd be easy to figure out what I'm trying to do, and where I am facing issues.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="UITest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UITest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="519" Width="656">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Width="60" Height="30" Content="button" Margin="10 10 0 0" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Bisque" FontSize="16">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <StackPanel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>

        <Label x:Name="label1" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="10 10 0 0" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" Content="label">
        </Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace UITest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        bool isClick2Done = true;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.button1.Click += Button1_Click1;
        }

        //primary function of button
        private async void Button1_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Content = "primary";

            //wait for a second, to avoid human error of double click
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            changeButtonFunction();
        }

        //secondary function of button
        private async void Button1_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isClick2Done = false;   //click2 isn't done yet
            label1.Content = "secondary";

            //delay function
            //to observe whether this secondary method gets completed or not
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            label1.Content = "secondary after wait";
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            isClick2Done = true;   //click2 is now done
            restoreButtonFunction();
        }

        private async void changeButtonFunction()
        {
            //set new function for button
            this.button1.Click -= Button1_Click1;
            this.button1.Click += Button1_Click2;

            //button is now green - indicator that button has new function
            button1.Background = Brushes.Green;

            //keep new function for specific seconds
            //is there a better way of doing this?
            await Task.Delay(3000);

            //restore original button function
            while(!isClick2Done) { }
            restoreButtonFunction();
        }

        private async void restoreButtonFunction()
        {
            button1.Background = Brushes.Bisque;
            label1.Content = "label";
            this.button1.Click -= Button1_Click2;
            this.button1.Click += Button1_Click1;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I think the problem is - restoreButtonFuntion() gets completed before Button1_Click2() does... I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use timer for that and one common event handler.

When user clicks first time,  start the timer. Set timer interval of 3000 ms.  So when the timer tick is handled restore primary functionality. During button click for first time do primary functionality and start timer.

You can use a flag also for identifying the second click in the same handler. Reset the flag when timer tick handled at 3000 ms.

This is also achievable using relay commands and interactivity by setting canExecute properly.

Comment: Could you elaborate the "flag for identifying the second click"?

Comment: Actually your code seems to be incorrect somewhere. I still don't understand why those delays everywhere. 

I was saying that. You could do primary click action first when user clicks for the first time  and then start a timer for 3 seconds. When timer tick handled at 3 seconds, change to **click one**. If user clicks again while timer is running, use click 2 action. This could be achieved with a **flag** to identify timer is running and reduce lines of code. No need to use 2 handlers.

Comment: those delays are just for testing purposes, they don't mean anything... I got it to work by doing what you said... thanks